# node app command doesn't display anything

Tags: node.js

I'm following [this article](http://www.codemag.com/article/1210041) to start using node.js. I got to the part where I should start my app with `node app` command. However, upon typing in the command and pressing enter, I just get a new input line.

```
C:\Users\Raketa\Desktop\workout-tracker>npm install -d
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.8.1
npm info using node@v5.9.0
...
npm info ok

C:\Users\Raketa\Desktop\workout-tracker>node app

C:\Users\Raketa\Desktop\workout-tracker>
```

The article says I should get

> Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode.

**Edit**:

Upon going to http://localhost:3000, it displays `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` site saying

> This site can’t be reached

**Edit2**:

*app.js* as requested:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the application is running at least? For instance try accessing `http://localhost:3000/`on your machine.

Comment: No, it says "This site can’t be reached" with the usual connection refused site.

Comment: can you put your `app.js` file in the question?

Comment: I didn't change anything. node.js created it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something missing in your file (or in the tutorial if you did it step by step). you are missing the actual command to start the server. You should have this (taken from the tutorial's [github](https://github.com/donnfelker/workout-tracker/blob/master/app.js)):

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %s in %s mode.",  app.get('port'), app.settings.env);
});
```

This is the command that actually starts the server and tells it to listen

What you have is just a file that builds the root of your express server, and only exports it (this is why it exits immediately instead of listening for requests).

Add this instead of the `module.exports = app;` at the end of your file

Comment: I'm not currently home, but I can see that the code from github repo is completely different from file node.js generated. I think the article is outdated since I followed it step by step and haven't changed the code.

Answer (score 3):

As it is, the app does not listen on any port - please see my suggested modifications to the `app.js` file:

Please add something like this at the end of the file (before `module.exports = app;` line):

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    log.info('Express server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Give it a try and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I don't think he needs the module.exports in this case- if app.js starts the server, there won't be any other file to require it

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit embarrassing... but I didn't save my app.js file. That caused the behavior the OP describes.

I saved it and reran `node app.js` and it worked.